# How to make multiple virtual machines publicly accessible behind a small business router?

Tags: routing, nat, switch

For simplicity, let's say we have 3x virtual machines each with their own static IP address on the basic small business router. What is the best way to configure 'things' to ensure each can be publicly accessible such as (which all point to the same home IP address);

- one.example.com
- two.example.com
- three.example.com
- ns.example.com
- smtp.example.com

Even on a basic small business router the DMZ is generally only configurable either to a single IP address for all inbound traffic, or if you can do port forwarding often this is limited to basic static options rather than the full range of ports.

I'm wondering the best approach to take to achieve this outcome. i.e. it is a case of going down the route of purchasing a better small business router? Or is it best to throw in a managed switch after the router, where then all inbound traffic in the DMZ can point to that switch and then it's the switch doing the port and hostname (is this possible?) routing?

Comment: What is the model of the router you are trying to use?

Comment: The model of the router isn't important, I'm looking for more of a best practice answer. I can purchase the relevant router if necessary.

Comment: The model of router has a major impact. You can use a cheap $100 router to do port forwarding and then use a reverse proxy, or you can use something like a Cisco or Mikrotik router which can be configured with multiple public IP addresses and then port forwarding from each IP address to each server.

Answer (score 3):

Well you already know how: Use port forwarding. Of course, a single port can only ever be forwarded to one host. So you’ll end up with, say, `http://one.example.com`, `http://two.example.com:81`, `http://three.example.com:82`, …

If you don’t want that, you’ll have to use a reverse proxy (nginx, Traefik, …) to have it terminate TLS (if any) and then forward to the correct host based on the `Host` header.

With OpenWrt or the like you could also run the reverse proxy on your router, with limited performance.

(DMZ is a misnomer in almost all cases including this one. You can set up an “exposed host”.)

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning **reverse proxy**. IMO that's the way to go: forward all traffic to a single nginx instance and let it handle any domain names as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IPv6. Designate one or more /64 subnets to contain public facing things, and assign IP addresses out of that. Assuming it is not possible to acquire more IPv4 addresses, this is the only way to get the

v4 remains tricky, particularly ingress. One IP address means you only get one of any given well known port, like 443/tcp. Port forward to a load balancer, probably reverse proxy based, and put hosts behind that. Map to backend servers via http Host headers, or some other application level scheme.